# Moving average on the frequency domain - (Welch's Method?)

Tags: fft, audio, moving-average

Is there a name for a filter that is using a moving average on the frequency domain?

I am searching for such a filter to filter out long "pads" (synths) from music.

Do any of you know about such software?

Comment: Not sure if I know what you mean. Do you want to average frequency bins, i.e. reduce the resolution in the frequency domain?

Comment: Yes, I want to average frequency bins. (But I think it reduces the resolution on time domain -- I'm no expert in DSP)

Comment: So you compute a short-time Fourier transform and in each frame you want to average the frequency bins before transforming back to the time domain and reconstructing?

Comment: Yes. Is it a novel idea or is there such a filter out there made by somebody else already? matlab, vst, etc.

Comment: It's also done in the feature extraction stage of speech recognizers, but there the time domain signal is not reconstructed, so the dimension in the frequency domain is reduced. The frequency bins are usually averaged using triangular kernels. This stage is referred to as 'filter bank' (but note that this is not what is commonly understood under a filter bank). Check out this document, there's also some code in it: http://www.cic.unb.br/~lamar/te073/Aulas/mfcc.pdf